# How to Open APK File in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to open an apk file from within my activity the following way:

```
File.openAttachment(attachmentName: String, context: Context, activity: Activity, mimeType: String) {

    if (attachmentName.isNotEmpty() && attachmentName != "-") {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

            intent.setDataAndType(this.getFileURI(), mimeType.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))

        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.choose_an_app)))
    }
}

File(Utils.getAttachmentPathDirectory(MyApplication.applicationContext())+"/apkTest.apk")
.openAttachment("apkTest.apk", this, this, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
```

i also tried the following way:

```
val intent_install =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent_install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent_install.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.packageName+".provider",File(Utils.getAttachmentPathDirectory(MyApplication.applicationContext())+"/"+fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
mActivity?.startActivity(intent_install)
```

there are no errors but the file is not opening

any help is appreciated

Comment: What does `getFileURI()` do and what does it return? If it is using anything other than `FileProvider`, it is likely that is the source of your difficulty.

Comment: Also note that `ACTION_VIEW` for installing an APK is at least deprecated on Android 10 and might no longer be supported. We are supposed to use the `PackageInstaller` API. See https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller for a sample app.

Comment: you have defined external-paths in paths.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @CommonWare and the provided link 
https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller

i have managed to achieve what i want using the following code

```
val apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, packageName+".provider", File(Utils.getAttachmentPathDirectory(MyApplication.applicationContext())+"/testapk.apk"))

MyApplication.applicationContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(apkUri).use { apkStream ->
            val length = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(application, apkUri)?.length() ?: -1
            val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
            val sessionId = installer.createSession(params)
            val session = installer.openSession(sessionId)

            session.openWrite(NAME, 0, length).use { sessionStream ->
                apkStream?.copyTo(sessionStream)
                session.fsync(sessionStream)
            }

            val intent = Intent(application, InstallReceiver::class.java)
            val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                application,
                PI_INSTALL,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )

            session.commit(pi.intentSender)
            session.close()
        }





class InstallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        when (val status = intent.getIntExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS, -1)) {
            PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION -> {
                val activityIntent =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra<Intent>(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT)

                context.startActivity(activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
            }
            PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS ->
                ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100)
                    .startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_ACK)
        }
    }
}
```